# FullpageJS horizontal scrolling not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, fullpage.js

I'm developing a website that heavily uses [FullpageJS](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/):

http://dev.oxplore.surge.online/

On the very first section, I've got a horizontal scrolling section with six slides. I can scroll between them all the way to the last-but-one slide. After that, the plugin loops back to the first slide, despite loopHorizontal being set to false.

The issue is most likely caused by a problem in my own CSS/JS, since making a from-scratch demo of Fullpage horizontal scrolling works fine. But I can't figure out what's interfering, so I thought I'd ask here for help.

*Note: a lot of JS re-arrangement of the page structure happens before Fullpage is called. However, the HTML is definitely in the right structure when Fullpage is called, so it should work.

*Note: the site is developed on a Drupal back-end (not my choice), but that shouldn't be affecting the plugin.

#### Steps to reproduce it

1. Scroll horizontally through the slides in the first section
2. After reaching slide 5, press right-arrow again.
3. Instead of advancing to slide 6, we loop back to slide 1 again.

#### Versions

Chrome, Firefox, IE, Mobile, etc

Comment: I know the issue is most likely in my own code. I'm not expecting a miracle answer, but thought I'd post anyway in case someone's come across this issue before and had tips.